# Extract Date from File Name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a file name like `abcdef_ghijkl_01172023.csv` and I want to extract the date `2023-01-17` from this string.

I was trying to use something like this:

```
convert(datetime, cast(substring(FileName, (patindex('%[0-9]%', FileName)), 8) as date), 103)
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Can you please help?

Comment: Because you are extracting "01172023", and not "2023-01-17" (or "20230117") ?

Comment: @Luuk yes trying to extract 01172023 and then converting to date format 2023-01-17. But need some help on how to do that.

Comment: You can use: `select cast(stuff(stuff('01172023',5,0,'-'),3,0,'-') as date);`   (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/Q9RLQ6pw )

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @filename NVARCHAR(100) = 'abcdef_ghijkl_01172023.csv'
DECLARE @dateString NVARCHAR(8) = SUBSTRING(@filename, CHARINDEX('_', @filename) + 1, CHARINDEX('.', @filename) - CHARINDEX('_', @filename) - 1)
DECLARE @inputDateFormat NVARCHAR(10) = 'MMddyyyy'
DECLARE @outputDateFormat NVARCHAR(10) = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, @dateString, @inputDateFormat), 120) AS formattedDate
```

Comment: this gives error : "Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 3 of convert function."

Comment: Can you try the edited one

Comment: The [error](https://dbfiddle.uk/DDkh9bPX) is because of the extra "_" in the filename.  (and, of course, because of not testing... `)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @filename NVARCHAR(100) = 'abcdef_ghijkl_01172023.csv';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT raw_date = PARSENAME(REPLACE(@filename, '_', '.'), 2)
)
SELECT raw_date
    , result = TRY_CAST(RIGHT(raw_date,4) + LEFT(rs.raw_date,2) + SUBSTRING(rs.raw_date,3,2) AS DATE)
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

| raw_date | result |
| --- | --- |
| 01172023 | 2023-01-17 |